# Google Action - playing youtube video on google hub

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

How can I play a specific Youtube Video on my Google Hub via Google Actions? I know I can use a Basic Card to display images and text and even a link (although that link does not show up on the HUB)

I specifically want to be able to trigger or to play a youtube video on my Google Hub.

Comment: in which device you want to display the youtube video? A TV? a PC?

Answer (score 1):

Actions are not able to start playing video content. [Media responses](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses) are only for audio.

Comment: Hi Nick, there is any way to play a video content (say from youtube) triggered by an Action on Google?

Comment: You can create a link from something like a card to YouTube, but that isn't guaranteed to work on every surface, and wouldn't automatically open the video.

Comment: Thanks Nick, you confirm what I guessed. The application I'm thinking about (in interactive narrative realms, would select video (youtube) contents from a voice dialog (action on google) and possibly directly stream the selected video clips (list of). The output device could be a smartdisplay, a web browser or a TV. Question: in the last case. I'm able to do youtube live streaming via chromecast maybe (through GoogleHome)?  Any idea?

Comment: The platform doesn't expose capabilities to do casting.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar need. After a chat with an action on google, I want to play user requested youtube videos (chains-of) on a local "big screen" (TV-like / PC).

A workaround solution could be:

1. you realize an action that select one or more videos.
   The action act also as a server for a client described here below
2. The action communicate (SSE, websocket, HTTP...) with a client browser page containing a javascript small program that dynamically visualize the video (id sent via SSE client-server communication)

Here below the rough js script (I'm not a web developer); that just gives you the idea:

```
<script language="javascript">

function loadVideoWithId(id) {
  const tvEmbedMode = "embed/" //"tv#/watch?v="
  const url = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${id}?fs=1&autoplay=1&loop=1` // 
  const iframe = `<iframe src="${url}" width="1600" height="900" allowFullScreen="allowFullScreen" frameBorder="0" />`
  document.write(iframe)
}

loadVideoWithId('hHW1oY26kxQ')

</script>
```